# shell script sum in for loop not working

Tags: bash, shell

```
size=`ls -l /var/temp.* | awk '{ print $5}'`
        fin_size=0
        for row in ${size} ;
        do      
                 fin_size=`echo $(( $row + $fin_size )) | bc`;
        done
echo $fin_size
```

is not working !! `echo $fin_size` is throwing some garbage minus value.
where I'm mistaking?
(my bash is old  and I suppose to work in this only Linux kernel: 2.6.39)

Comment: As dogbane suggested, you should never parse the output of `ls` (read [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) why), so this and the accepted answer is the wrong approach to your problem. Use `du`, `stat` or `find`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below should be enough:

```
ls -l /var/temp.*  | awk '{a+=$5}END{print a}'
```

No need for you to run the for loop.This means:

```
size=ls -l /var/temp.* | awk '{ print $5}'`
        fin_size=0
        for row in ${size} ;
        do      
                 fin_size=`echo $(( $row + $fin_size )) | bc`;
        done
echo $fin_size
```

The whole above thing can be replaced with :

```
fin_size=`ls -l /var/temp.*  | awk '{a+=$5}END{printf("%10d",a);}'`
echo $fin_size
```

Comment: answer is : 2.61708e+09 I need like 1234341231

Comment: change the print a to printf ("%10d",a);

Comment: Somebody has given..not me

Comment: The downvote is probably for parsing the output of `ls`; it's not guaranteed to work in all cases, and should not be suggested as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Why not use `du` as shown below?

```
du -cb /var/temp.* | tail -1
```

Comment: +1 for the link to Greg's wiki and the `du` suggestion; just noting that `tail -1` is deprecated and you should use `tail -n 1` instead.

Comment: why it is giving more values than 'ls parse' ? for eg. above answer is 931234 and with this command its 951252

Answer (score 1):

Because it cannot be stressed enough: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Use e.g. `du` as suggested by dogbane, or `find`:

```
$ find /var -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "temp.*" -printf "%s\n" | awk '{total+=$1}END{print total}'
```

or `stat`:

```
$ stat -c%s /var/temp.* | awk '{total+=$1}END{print total}'
```

or [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and `stat` (unnecessary, slow):

```
total=0
for file in /var/temp.*; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
    size="$(stat -c%s "${file}")"
    ((total+=size))
done
echo "${total}"
```

Comment: Piping the output of `find` to `awk` will fail under the same circumstances that piping the output of `ls` will fail: when the file name contains a newline character.

Comment: @chepner You did not look closely enough, I am only outputting the *size* of the files in question.

Comment: @chepner No worries. Probably my fault for not explaining the code.